# jQuery on handling virtual keyboard click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-keyboard-with-css-and-jquery--net-5774) he is makin a virtual keyboard using jQuery. I am making a virtual keyboard by using the foundation this tutorial. But I noticed a problem in this tutorial's keyboard. When I enter a character to the text area using my physical keyboard and after trying to enter a character via the virtual keyboard, virtual keyboard is not working. I have to refresh the page to get it work. It works properly until I enter something directly to the textarea from my physical keyboard.

I would like to implement some customized keyboard by using this keyboard's logic. But the "bug" I mentioned above blocks my path. Could someone help me with what is going on there? Thank you.

My code to add button's content to textarea:

```
<textarea id='tx'></textarea>
<div class='key'>1</div>
<div class='key'>2</div>
<div class='key'>3</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.key').click(function() {
         $('#tx').html( $(this).html() );
    });
});
```

Comment: What error are you getting? And can you create a Fiddle or something?

Comment: I get no errors. After I touched my physical keyboard, my virtual keyboard doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your code

**from this**

```
 // Delete
        if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
            var html = $write.html();

            $write.html(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
            return false;
        }
```

**to this**

```
if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
            var html = $write.val();

            $write.val(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
            return false;
        }
```

and finally
**from this**

```
$write.html($write.html() + character);
```

**to this**

```
$write.val($write.val() + character);
```

Because you are changing `val()` not `html()`. That Blog has errors too. Correct it.